# Installing an event filter on a QTableView to prevent delegate closing

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to allow for selecting other indices while editing the content of a cell in a (custom) `QTableView`. My `QTableView` uses a custom delegate.

In order to do this, since clicking another cell causes the delegate to close its editor, I've tried to add an event filter to my `QTableView`.

```cpp
// Constructor
viewport()->installEventFilter(this);
```

```cpp
bool Table::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *ev) 
{
    auto mouseEvent = dynamic_cast<QMouseEvent*>(ev);
    if (!mouseEvent)
        return false;

    if (mouseEvent->type() == QEvent::MouseMove)
        return false;

    // editing_ is a state attribute that describes whether the user is editing a cell
    if (editing_)
    {
        if (mouseEvent->button() == Qt::MouseButton::LeftButton)
        {
            selectedCell = model()->data(indexAt(mouseEvent->pos()), Qt::UserRole).value<SpreadsheetCell*>();
            qDebug() << "User selected" << selectedCell->id();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, things don't happen in the right order, and I only get to catch the event *after* the editor has been closed. See:

```cpp
void MyDelegate::commitAndCloseEditor()
{
    // ...
    qDebug() << "Closing editor"; 
    // ...
}
```

My debug output:

```
Creating editor
User selected "D4" <- This is triggered when the editor has just been opened, not when the editor is closing
Closing editor
```

It seems like my event filter catches the events after they've already been propagated to children, which kind of kills the purpose... Please suggest.

Comment: This approach looks a little bit complex at first glance. Did you already try to use this function `QAbstractItemView::openPersistentEditor()`?

Comment: I thought that `openPersistentEditor` use case wasn't really what I had here, according to Qt docs. I've tried it out since, but haven't really been able to get much out of it yet.